# How to get categorized list of all entities in a particular area of Google Maps/Open Street Maps?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, google-earth, address

[image: Entities in a particular area]

I have been asked by my Professor to get the list of all kinds of entities for a particular area.

Here by entities I mean - Names and(or) Addresses categorically resolved to

- residential area,
- restaurants,
- service stations or
- any other possible category.

I am new to this field so I did some google search on how to get the list of such data for a particular area but was unable to find useful.

Is there any API for getting such data?

I don't want any code, I want people to point me in the right direction/give me some references.

Comment: Take a look at OSM and [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is unlikely that you will be able to batch download all of [Google Data](https://support.google.com/mapmaker/answer/156852?hl=en). However, you can tap into Google Data using the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details).

If you are interested in OpenStreetMap use [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) zoom to your area of interest with the Mapview port as the area you will download using the Bounding Box code:

```
node
  ({{bbox}});
out;
```

[image]

Of course this will only get you Nodes (points). you will have to repeat for polygons, and lines.

or take the easy route and download a batch of all OSM data using [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/).
Click your Sub-Region
[image]

Click your region
[image]
Click your Subregion of the Region
[image]

then once you have picked your area click .shp.zip (or whatever format you want)

---

When you have your data (from whichever method you use) then take the data into QGIS and select Analysis Tools > List Unique Values. That will give you a list. you will have to organize on your own. [image]

in ArcGIS use the technical article on [Identifying Duplicate Field Values](http://support.esri.com/cN/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38700). In this case, the results that have a '0' in the field...this would make them unique and allow you to cluster for analysis.

Comment: You don't have to "repeat for polygons, and lines", you can query all types of elements with Overpass API at once.